# Risk to Windows 10 of installing Window 8 driver

Tags: windows-10, windows-8, drivers

Based on the thread HP forum thread at https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Printer-Software-and-Drivers/HP-PSC-750-and-Windows-10/td-p/6497660, I searched for old printer drivers at http://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=hp+psc+750+%22windows+10%22.  The only thing that comes up are Windows 8 drivers.

Is there a risk to the OS from attempting to install Windows 8 drivers on Windows 10?

Please note that even though the examples are specific, the question is not specific to a product.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104160/discussion-on-question-by-user2153235-risk-to-windows-10-of-installing-window-8). If any comments are necessary to provide information on your problem then please [edit] them into your question before the chat room is frozen or deleted as this will help future visitors with the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a new Windows 10 machine, you do not need Windows 8 Drivers. Let Windows 10 update the drivers. Look in Updates, Advanced options and allow Updates to update other products.

Normally you would unplug the Printer first, then plug it back in and search for drivers.

Also you can leave the Update Setting to find other updates ON

**The procedure in detail**

- Under Windows Updates, Advanced options, turn on the switch for "Receive updates for other Microsoft products...", then initiate an update
- Unplug the peripheral from the USB port and plug it back in.
- If successful, you see messages that Windows recognized the printer and set it up.

Answer (score 1):

> The only thing that comes up is Windows 8 drivers.

Only four of those drivers you linked to are actually for **Windows 8 and later**.  However, those 4 drivers, only support specific languages and are likely NOT compatible with your Windows installation.  The rest of the drivers are not compatible with Windows 10.

However, I was able to find [printer drivers](https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/ScopedViewInline.aspx?updateid=4a8eb67c-2c94-4d8d-b5f8-9d922322f1e8) for `usb\vid_03f0&pid_1411&rev_0100` that specifically support Windows 10. `usb\vid_03f0&pid_1411&rev_0100` is the same hardware id, that [Hewlett-Packard - Imaging, Printing - HP PSC 750 USB](https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=hp%20psc%20750%20%22windows%2010%22) supports.  This is an indication that the [Windows 10 drivers](https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/ScopedViewInline.aspx?updateid=4a8eb67c-2c94-4d8d-b5f8-9d922322f1e8) will support your device.

> Is there a risk to the OS from attempting to install Windows 8 drivers on Windows 10?

Windows 8 drivers do not typically support Windows 10.  A device driver must specifically support Windows 10.  The biggest risk in trying to use an unsupported driver is if for some reason Windows actually does allow you to use it, you would have an unstable system that is difficult to diagnose.

There are absolutely no security concerns using a signed driver from the Windows catalog.

Comment: Hardware ID determines if the driver is compatible with the device.  [Download](https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=usb%5Cvid_03f0%26pid_1411%26rev_0100) the first driver.  I spent a considerable amount of time writing this answer.  I literally indicated which driver to use.

Comment: Hi, Ramhound.  I very much appreciate the time and effort you put into your answer. I'm hesitant to follow through with it because John's solution lets Windows decide how to update drivers, so I don't have to do any finagling. I'd like to upvote your answer, but I don't feel that I can mark it as the answer since I would first have to try the solution.  Sorry!